# Hashing a seed full of entropy with a cryptographic hash function and emiting a key with the same size as input: can a collision attack occurs?

Tags: hash, keys, entropy, collision-attack, seed

I read this in the [documentation of HighwayHash](https://github.com/google/highwayhash#defending-against-hash-flooding):

> By contrast, 'strong' hashes such as SipHash or HighwayHash require
> infeasible attacker effort to find a hash collision (an expected 2^32
> guesses of m per the birthday paradox) or recover the seed (2^63
> requests). These security claims assume the seed is secret. It is
> reasonable to suppose s is initially unknown to attackers, e.g.
> generated on startup or even per-connection. A timing attack by
> Wool/Bar-Yosef recovers 13-bit seeds by testing all 8K possibilities
> using millions of requests, which takes several days (even assuming
> unrealistic 150 us round-trip times). It appears infeasible to recover
> 64-bit seeds in this way.

/\ This is talking about 64-bits output.

Let's suppose I take a 256-bits seed full of entropy from Linux `/dev/hwrng` and hash with a (cryptographic) hash function.

Based on that said above, can the adversary brute-force the seed space and find a collision with 2^128 guesses (128-bits)? Or will it have to brute-force the entire seed space to find the matching key (256-bits)?

This question could sound obvious, but the documentation of HighwayHash made me confused.

Comment: Hiya!  But what is `/dev/hwrng `? The NSA don't like that kinda stuff.

Comment: I answered but I deleted my answer. SipHash is a keyed hash and is used to prevent very specific attacks against hash tables. I'm not entirely sure that you are trying to use it in a way for which it is designed. As I'm unaware of the context I think my answer is void of meaning.

Comment: @PaulUszak I have been reading about conspiracies about the TRNG of Inter processors be backdoored, but I use AMD. I cited /dev/hwrng as an example, here I use CPU jittering as my main entropy source for avoiding any possibility of my hardware has the NSA hands. haha! I'm realy paranoid.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes I just wanna know if I hash a key with 256-bits of size and entropy I would get another key with the same criptographic strenght.

Comment: ... with a 64 bit output? Huh? Sorry, by now I'm just confused.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes That was an example, there are variants of HighwayHash that outputs 128 and 256-bits respectively.

Comment: @PaulUszak It is a reference to RDRAND in Intel and AMD processors (and probably similar instructions on ARM processors). So it might well be that NSA *does* like that stuff, according to your own reasoning.